# Isothermal irreversible expansion of ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, carnot-cycle

I am studying Thermodynamics in my first year and I don't quite understand the process of isothermal reversible/irreversible expansion. Below is a P-V graph I found on Google, just to help me illustrate my question here.

[image]

My question is: why does the irreversible process take the path under the curve (the red route)? Why can't it take the path above the curve (the blue route)? I tried to figure out why this is not happening. For a process to be spontaneous, the overall entropy (system and surrounding) should be positive. But I couldn't see how entropy comes anywhere in this graph. Please shed some light on this.

Comment: What do you get if you do a force balance on the massless piston during the irreversible deformation?

Comment: Thermodynamics is confusing!! Please help me!!

Comment: The image is taken from https://slideplayer.com/amp/10212156/ Please go through this slide player. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not take the red curve, nor the blue. It does not take *any* curve
on that graph.

The P-V graph you show is a phase diagram. Each point represents a
*equilibrium state* of the system. In reversible expansion, the system is at each time at equilibrium. Then, you can draw its trajectory on the graph. However, in irreversible expansion the system goes out of equilibrium. In this case, there is no trajectory that you can draw
on a phase diagram! You can only draw the initial and final points.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I found on my text book: Thermodynamics and statistical mechanics by John M. Seddon， it represents the irreversible path with the red route and explicitly says "the irreversible process is carried out by suddenly lowering the pressure"

Comment: I found that passage and I find it misleading, at best. I guess you refer to Fig. 2.7 Chapter 2, pag. 10. Notice that in the book the y axis is p_ex. Then yes, if you keep volume constant and change p_ex you are going on that path. But this is _not_ the P-V diagram of the system!

Comment: Notice also that there can be indeed _reversible_ processes that trace the red and blue curve in your graph. These are called [isochoric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochoric_process) and [isobaric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isobaric_process) processes. These ones are reversible and can be drawn on the P-V diagram.

Comment: According to text books,the reversible follows the green line curve.Red & blue processes Pi ->Vf are irreversible.This is because in these processes you must give and take heat from the gas. – elias2010 8 mins ago    Edit   Delete

Comment: @elias2010 This is wrong. Please have a look at the links in my other comment. Moreover, also in the isothermal reversible expansion there is heat exchange. No heat exchange is in a adiabatic process. These are different concepts.

Comment: 1)Isobaric expansion can be spontaneous so irreversible by heat absorption from the surround 2)Isochoric decompression can be spontaneous so irreversible by heat desorption to the surround.

Comment: @elias2010 Spontaneous does not imply irreversible. Again these are different concepts. Than, of course isobaric and isochoric processes *can* be irreversible, but they *need not* to!

Comment: @fra_pero Yes, your guess is very correct. So, how should one represent the irreversible path on a P-V diagram, previously you said that there is no way to draw it on a phase diagram(Pressure against temperature)

Comment: @FëanorTang You can't represent in a rigorous way the irreversible process on a P-V diagram, because during the process the system is out of equilibrium. You can make a sketch, like a wiggle line between initial and final point. This would be just a symbol, not a proper curve in the P-V diagram.

Comment: @FëanorTang Bear in mind that (at least elementary) thermodynamics is about equilibrium states, which can be described by few parameters T, P, etc. which are the same throughout the system. The description of out-of-equilibrium states is a much more involved problem (e.g. T may not be uniform). This is not your concern here. If you are given an irreversible process, you should be concerned only about the final and initial states.

Comment: @FëanorTang The plot in the book you cite is *not* wrong; I would say misleading. There, the y axis is the external pressure. This is *not* the pressure of the system during the irreversible process. Indeed, if during the process, at each time, the external pressure is the same as the pressure of the system, then the process is reversible.

Comment: @fra_pero Thank you very much for your reply:)

Comment: Good answer and discussion. Note that in this specific case, the P-V plot is actually an *indicator diagram* (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_diagram).